# Are cubical higher Chow groups of field $CH^{n-1}(F,n)$ generated by linear cycles?

Tags: motivic-cohomology, algebraic-cycles, chow-groups

In the paper "The linearization of higher Chow cycles of dimension one" W. Gerdes proved that Higher Chow homology group $CH^{n-1}(F,n)=H^{n}(z^{n-1}(F,*))$ are generated by linear cycles.

> Is it known the corresponding statement for cubical Higher Chow group?

As M. Levine proved they are isomorphic but it is not clear for me that this isomorphism preserves linear cycles.

Is it possible to generalise Gerdes's arguments so that it would work for cubical Higher Chow group as well?

I am intersted in the case when $F$ is algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. We can work tensor $\mathbb Q$.

Any ideas are welocome!